# Modern (2015) pet shop store to compare technology stacks

Tags: java, programming

In 2001, Sun created the [Pet Shop Store](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-136650.html) application. The application was implemented on many technology stacks (even .NET later) so developers could compare mesaures like development time and learning curve.

I am looking for a similar application as I would like to measure the technology stack we implemented. The application should meet the following requirements:

- is as simple as possible (we would not like to spend weeks or months to implement it)
- has a good system design documentation
- implemented on many stacks for comparison
- has authentication and authorization
- has a modern web design
- has to handle AJAX queries (and optionally websocket, or other newer query types)
- needs to store some persistent data

Answer (score 1):

I think Todo applications are commonly used to evaluate technology stacks. For example there is [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) with examples for many JavaScript frameworks.

A full example including the backend of such an application (using Java 8, Spark, MongoDB, and AngularJS) is provided in this [blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/developing-single-page-web-applications-using-java-8-spark-mongodb-and-angularjs/) for example.